# Run setup for selected parameter combinations in pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

In one of my project tests, I have some function that needs to be tested with a large parameter space. This function has a large overhead and additionally, the calculation for each parameter set takes quite some time. It is thus beneficial to run the calculation with all parameters at once and then use the results in the individual tests. Also, I introduced a marker which allows me to select different parameter sets. One parameter set is used during development while the other parameter set runs over night. Now, in this specific project, there are some more markers and people use them for different purposes. Thus, I would like to access the selected parameter sets in my setup fixture to provide the results for all parameter sets that are tested in a specific run.

The following shows a minimal example of the test:

```
import pytest
import time


class Parametrization(object):
    PARAM_A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    PARAM_B = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
    NAMES = "param_a,param_b"

    QUICK_PARAM_SPACE = [
        (0, 20),
        (4, 50)]

    def parameter_list(self):
        return [
            (param_a, param_b)
            for param_a in self.PARAM_A
            for param_b in self.PARAM_B]

    @staticmethod
    def param_id(param_a, param_b):
        return "A_{param_a}_B_{param_b}".format(
            param_a=param_a, param_b=param_b)

    @property
    def pytest_param_decorator(self):
        parameters = []
        for (param_a, param_b) in self.parameter_list():
            if (param_a, param_b) in self.QUICK_PARAM_SPACE:
                parameters.append(pytest.param(
                    param_a, param_b,
                    id=self.param_id(param_a, param_b)))
            else:
                parameters.append(pytest.param(
                    param_a, param_b,
                    id=self.param_id(param_a, param_b),
                    marks=pytest.mark.extended_parameter_set))

        return pytest.mark.parametrize(self.NAMES, parameters)


PARAM = Parametrization()


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def job_result():
    """
    This function runs some calculation that is expensive for each parameter
    set but also has some overhead, so it's much cheaper to run it with all
    parameter sets at once than running it for each parameter set individually.
    """

    print("Simulated overhead")
    time.sleep(1)

    result = {}
    for param_a, param_b in PARAM.parameter_list():
        print("Calculate parameter combination {} - {}.".format(
            param_a, param_b))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        result[(param_a, param_b)] = param_a + param_b

    yield result


@PARAM.pytest_param_decorator
def test_example(job_result, param_a, param_b):
    assert job_result[param_a, param_b] == param_a + param_b
```

Running this test using

```
py.test test_example.py -s -m "not extended_parameter_set"
```

will correctly run "test_example" only the parameter combinations "A_0_B_20" and "A_4_B_50". However, it will still calculate all the other parameter combinations in "job_result". What I would need is to access the selected parameter combinations in the function "job_result" so I can only run the calculation for the selected parameter combinations. Is there a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can actually be achieved quite easily using the request fixture. With that, it is possible to just loop over the requested items and get the parameters from there:

```
for item in request.session.items:
    if item.get_marker("skip") is not None:
        continue
    param_a = item.callspec.getparam("param_a")
    param_b = item.callspec.getparam("param_b")
    ...
```

The full example then reads as:

```
import pytest
import time


class Parametrization(object):
    PARAM_A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    PARAM_B = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
    NAMES = "param_a,param_b"

    QUICK_PARAM_SPACE = [
        (0, 20),
        (4, 50)]

    def parameter_list(self):
        return [
            (param_a, param_b)
            for param_a in self.PARAM_A
            for param_b in self.PARAM_B]

    @staticmethod
    def param_id(param_a, param_b):
        return "A_{param_a}_B_{param_b}".format(
            param_a=param_a, param_b=param_b)

    @property
    def pytest_param_decorator(self):
        parameters = []
        for (param_a, param_b) in self.parameter_list():
            if (param_a, param_b) in self.QUICK_PARAM_SPACE:
                parameters.append(pytest.param(
                    param_a, param_b,
                    id=self.param_id(param_a, param_b)))
            else:
                parameters.append(pytest.param(
                    param_a, param_b,
                    id=self.param_id(param_a, param_b),
                    marks=pytest.mark.extended_parameter_set))

        return pytest.mark.parametrize(self.NAMES, parameters)


PARAM = Parametrization()


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def job_result(request):
    """
    This function runs some calculation that is expensive for each parameter
    set but also has some overhead, so it's much cheaper to run it with all
    parameter sets at once than running it for each parameter set individually.
    """

    print("Simulated overhead")
    time.sleep(1)

    result = {}
    for item in request.session.items:
        if item.get_marker("skip") is not None:
            continue
        param_a = item.callspec.getparam('param_a')
        param_b = item.callspec.getparam('param_b')
        print("Calculate parameter combination {} - {}.".format(
            param_a, param_b))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        result[(param_a, param_b)] = param_a + param_b

    yield result


@PARAM.pytest_param_decorator
def test_example(job_result, param_a, param_b):
    assert job_result[param_a, param_b] == param_a + param_b
```